# A codecademy (JavaScript) related question

Tags: javascript

So I am learning JavaScript from codecademy, and I have reached the functions part. Everything from the beginning towards the variables is easy. Once I got into functions, I started getting confused. I know function declaration, how to call a function, and how to show default values in case there is no info passed to the function. But the return function part is super confusing. I have used this code:

```
    function monitorCount(rows, columns) {
     return (rows * columns);
 }
 monitorCount(5, 4);
```

to basically calculate or return the the value of rows time the columns. Codecademy shows that the code has an error. Could someone please tell me if there is an error in my code here, and If it has an error, how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it should work to me, I think there's no need to wrap the (row * columns) in brackets, sometimes we use brackets like that if there's more operations in order to ensure things happen in the right order, but since you only have one operation here it shouldn't be unnecessary.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Also perhaps alter the title of your question to "Code shows an error in CodeAcademy" also are you sure you included all the code? there doesn't appear to be any problems with the above javascript in your question. Perhaps also tag the question with codeacademy (if there is a tag)

Comment: The code works fine, probably the brackets it's something that codeacademy does not like, usually those brackets are used when you have more operations. Remove those and you should be fine.

Comment: This works fine. Can you please tell what do you want it to do? Also, if you want to print the return value in the console, then you should try something like this: ```console.log(monitorCount(5, 4));```

Comment: What errors does it showed? And what's the context of your code?

Comment: Sabareesh, thank you for the reply. Your answer really helped. Regarding the title, it is my first time using this web, and I just started programming.

Comment: I guess my problem is the concept. Instead of calling the function, logging the operation in the function body, and then passing information (which is way simpler), we use the return function. WHY IS THAT?

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, make sure its asking you to return the value, not print it. Right now that last line does nothing. It returns a value and then does nothing with it. When you run monitorCount, you will want to do something with that return value, most liklely printing it using `console.log()`